Does every Holomorphic function satisfy Laplace's Equation?
Consider Holomorphic function $f(z)$
$$f(z) = f(x + iy) = u(x,y) + iv(x,y)$$
Every holomorphic function is the sum of harmonic functions $u(x,y)$, $v(x,y)$, and so it is also harmonic and solves Laplace's Equation
$$\nabla^2f = \nabla^2u + i\nabla^2v = 0 + 0 = 0$$
Is this correct in general?

Yes it's correct

We know that real and imaginary parts of any holomorphic function satisfy the Cauchy-Riemann equations. Consider the Cauchy-Riemann equations:
$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial v}{\partial y}$ and $\frac{\partial u}{\partial y} = - \frac{\partial v}{\partial x}$
Now differentiate the first equation wrt $x$ and the second wrt $y$ we will get $\frac{\partial^{2} u}{\partial^{2} x} = \frac{\partial^{2} v}{\partial x \partial y}$ and  $\frac{\partial^{2} u}{\partial^{2} y} = - \frac{\partial^{2} v}{\partial y \partial x}$
Adding both two equations will prove this result. Here, note that as $f$ is a holomorphic function, then $f$ is infinitely differentiable, and hence so are $u$ and $v$. That means $u$ and $v$ have continuous second partial derivatives.
